# Rename last chapter to epilogue,

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

First of all: I read through many possible solutions here, but none seem to work for me. I want to rename the last chapter of a book to be named "Epilogue" in the ToC and for all similar purposes AND have a 'real' name. So what I have now is:

Chapter heading:

[image]

Top of page in the epilogue:

[image]

Table of contents:

[image]

What I WOULD like to have is this:
[image]

So far I have tried putting different commands in front of the last `\chapter{}` but it usually changed only a part, and never worked on the ToC, so I figured the trick might be somewhere in the definition of the ToC. EDIT: This is the most minimal example that I can produce in a reasonable time by checking if something breaks when I comment out stuff, as I don't understand most of the advanced commands yet.

Bonus question: Could something be easily changed so that the odd and even side margins are different, so that it would be more suitable for printing?

```
\documentclass[12pt,extrafontsizes,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Once upon a time}
there was a princess (more text here, so that it is actually
at least 3 pages)
\fixepilogue
\chapter{Epilogue: Ending}
then she died (more text here, so that it is actually at
least 3 pages)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current behaviour? We're not interested in the nifty font, or all of the chapters you list... just something we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see a *regular* chapter followed by *another chapter* that you want to style to be different of.

Comment: Can it be 500 lines long? Because I really don't know what I can cut off, as it is just a template I am adapting, and its freakishly complicated :(

Comment: No, that's not minimal. The code you've provided thus far uses (just as an example), `\hp`, and `\IfInteger` and *we* have to figure out which package provides those or what they mean. Since we're suppose to help you, you should make it easy for us to get on the same page as you, regardless of how complex your current setup is.

Comment: identification of the `\documentclass` is absolutely necessary.  different classes define this element in different ways, and unless we know what to look at, we're just spinning out wheels.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize this. I try to cut out as much stuff as I can, and post it as an edit.

Comment: @MaximMoloshenko: Drop all the font-stuff, the `lettrine` stuff, the use of unnecessary stuff like `\Star` and `\Stars` in the header (yes, it's really not necessary), the page layout adjustments (since it has nothing to do with your requirement), the adjustment of ToC-related stuff... that's what is meant by a MWE. Ask yourself the quesion: Does keeping this information help with solving the problem? Or, does this add to the problem? If the answer is "no", then remove it and anything associated with it. Specifically, fonts here is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I managed to remove the `lettrine` stuff, and some of the fonts maybe, but I still think I have not gotten all of it. I do not mean to sound ungrateful or anything of the sort, but you see, its *really* advanced code for me, and not only do I not have an idea of what some commands do, sometimes I don't even understand what the command IS. So I really just comment stuff out line by line, and try to compile everything. Can I maybe make the question into wiki-style, so that anyone can delete unnecessary stuff?

Comment: Just add before the last chapter `\chaptername{Epilogue}`.

Comment: This doesn't work. What I can do is wipe the header with `\markboth{}{}` and then maybe somehow manually put in the right words. But the index is really tricky - there the *number* of the chapter is printed, so I have to maybe redefine this really complicated command that constructs the index. The actual heading of the chapter, I have no clue on how to deal with

Comment: BTW, you need to NOT specify [twoside] in the \documentclass if you want unequal margins.  Also, memoir does almost every itself (differently).

Comment: The edits have hidden the most relevant information. `:-(` Without knowing the chapter style, header and toc definitions, just guesses can be made.

Comment: That is true, but lucky for me dgoodmaniii saved me already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I trimmed your MWE to the point that it was, in fact, both minimal (no extraneous font information, formatting, and so forth) and working (it compiled without error).  I'm not going to duplicate your formatting; but the principle here works.

It appears that, for your TOC, you want the word "Epilogue" to replace your chapter number (which you give in words); the below code will do that.  It also places the word "Epilogue" and the name of the epilogue in the header, though it doesn't format the header the way yours does.  (You may need to switch the arguments in `\markboth` to make this work for you; I didn't pay attention to which you want where.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,extrafontsizes,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Once upon a time}
there was a princess (more text here, so that it is actually
at least 3 pages)
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Epilogue}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{Epilogue}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
    \markboth{Epilogue}{#1}%
    \vspace*{10pt}%
    \begin{center}%
    \LARGE%
    \chaptername%
    \vskip1em%
    \leavevmode#1%
    \end{center}%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
}%
\makeatother
\chapter{Ending}
then she died (more text here, so that it is actually at
least 3 pages)\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

What this code does is, just before your epilogue, redefine `\chaptername` to be "Epilogue" (this makes it print "Epilogue" instead of "Chapter") and it redefines your chapter number to be "Epilogue", as well (this makes it print "Epilogue" instead of a chapter number in your TOC).  It doesn't effect the chapter number itself, however, which internally is still the same.

It then redefines LaTeX's internal command `\@makechapterhead`, in ways that should be pretty transparent.  You can fix this to be formatted however you like.  Here's what this code gives you, though:

[image: Epilogue in TOC]
[image: Epilogue in Header]

I think this is the general outline of what you're looking for.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Should "Epilogue" and "Ending" both show up (and overlap) in the Table of Contents?

Comment: They should both show up, but not overlap; I just didn't duplicate his toc formatting. But those seem like the elements he wanted.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! Thank you so very much! I did some veeeeeery ugly things to save the formatting, but in the end your code was exactly the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Basically all you have to do is

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\ignorespaces}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{Epilogue}
\chapter{Ending}
```

since this is the last chapter in the document. The chapter counter will still be stepped, even though it's not necessary.

Comment: Won't this create an overlap of the words "Epilogue" and "Ending" in the ToC?

Comment: @Mico: The ToC prints the chapter number on a separate line, with the title underneath. So there should be no overlap.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I had failed to appreciate that the OP's ToC doesn't use a "standard" layout.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution is

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\ignorespaces}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{Epilogue}
\chapter{}
```

and I avoided the superposition.